# Script Timing Out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, limit, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I have the paid version of GSUITE (Personal/Basic) which I have been told allows my very basic script to run 3,200 times a day - All I am trying to do is populate a "zip code" column in my sheet based on addresses in another column.

Here is my script:

```
function geozipmh(a) {
    var response=Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat(a),long(a));
    return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',')[2].trim().split(' ')[1];
}
function lat(pointa) {
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(pointa);
    return response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
}
function long(pointa) {
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(pointa);
    return response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
}
```

And, on the sheet itself, in cell E2, I have: =geozipmh(D2) - D2 contains the full address.

The script works great, about 200 times then I get:

Service Invoked too many times in one day.geocode.Line 7

What on earth am I doing wrong?

I have spoken to Google Suite support

Comment: Have you verified it is not the maps portion that is running out of available calls? From the look of your script, you initialize it 3 few separate times.

Comment: Not sure I would know how to correct it?

Comment: Initialize it once and reuse the instance. You may want to check your API stats through the site, rather than relying on an error message. It will tell you where your calls are going. You have to keep in mind that Google has put recent strangle holds on Map-related items and their (corrupt) design has weighted costs, such as certain items counting as 2 calls.

Comment: Thanks - Can you explain how I would accomplish this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder may be a bit more help. I didn't realize the first call is a reverse geocode, but you may be able to reuse `var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(pointa);` to avoid making two separate calls by declaring it outside the function.

Comment: Is there any way you could show me where to put that in my code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview would be a good place to start and you can always post a new question if you run into trouble. You may also want to ask about the issue where you obtained the code, which I am assuming came from another source based on your responses.

Comment: Yes and thanks - I will refer to that link - I appreciate all the help